# Change Figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would need to change the figure size of the plot generated by the code below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df.index = df.Date
df.drop(["Date"],  axis=1, inplace=True)
df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plt.show()
```

On the x-axis I have 100 days and data are currently not easily readable. I have tried to use plt.figure, but unfortunately nothing has changed. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you move `plt.figure` above `df.plot`?

Comment: `df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(20,8))`

Comment: Where did you define df?

Comment: Hi Ann Zen, I defined the dataframe as follows `df = pd.read_csv("/path/dataset.csv", sep=';', engine='python') `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Create the figure of desired size
2. Pass the created axis to the `df.plot()` command

---

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8)) # <---- Create the figure of desired size

df.index = df.Date
df.drop(["Date"],  axis=1, inplace=True)
df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, ax=ax) # <---- Pass the created axis to plot
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))` before calling `df.plot()` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

    df.index = df.Date
    df.drop(["Date"],  axis=1, inplace=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))
    df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not change the figure size